# How to test a RGBLED without Raspberry Pi connection?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mocking, pwm, gpiozero

I was working with `gpiozero` and wanted to use the `MockFactory` to debug on a local device without Raspberry Pi (4) connection. The last time I used the `Mockfactory` was with an `gpiozero.LED` object. But this time I used a `gpiozero.RGBLED` output device. When I run my Programm I get the following error:
`gpiozero.exc.PinPWMUnsupported`

```
import gpiozero
from gpiozero.pins.mock import MockFactory

gpiozero.Device.pin_factory = MockFactory()
led = gpiozero.RGBLED(4, 3, 2)
```

I know that the `MockFactory` does not support PWM as stated in the documentation https://github.com/gpiozero/gpiozero/blob/master/gpiozero/pins/mock.py

> A mock pin used primarily for testing. This class does *not* support
> PWM.

How would I implement this functionality in order to test my programm without a connection to the Raspberry Pi?
Any help or pointers in the right direction are greatly appriciated!

Answer (score 1):

As RGBs are inherently PWM (the amount of red, green and blue is controlled with PWM), this won't work.

What you **could** do is just create some dummy output based on the values you want. You didn't write your intention, but you could make the values you'd want your RGBLED to have, and just print them for debugging.

Let me know if you want any other tips!

Comment: Trying the same thing... Not even sure if I it is the right use case for my context (testing code without RPi connection). Seems it's a classic, as a developement IDE on the pi quickly overwhelms it :-). Would it be better/cleaner to implement a PinFactory, that just returns constant values and ignores input?